# Powershell Script to uninstall Chrome

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, uninstallation

Trying to identify the setup.exe of Chrome and then perform a silent uninstall.
Get-ChildItem works without defining the varial $LocalVersion. Need to recall $LocalVersion to perform uninstall. Any clues?

```
# Uninstalling Chrome

$LocalVersion = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" -Filter "setup.exe" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | %{$_.FullName}).name
  
Start-Process -FilePath "$LocalVersion" -ArgumentList '-uninstall --system.level --multi-install --force-uninstall' -Verbose #-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue      

Start-Sleep 10
```

Recall $LocalVersion-Variable

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `().Name` from variable. It produces nothing